# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' when reading from JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.7, attributeerror

I am making a script for a school project that requires that I receive a JSON file that tells me if a license plate is visible in a picture. Right now the code sends a POST with an image to an API that then gives me a JSON in return, that JSON data is sent to the file "lastResponse.json."

**The code that is giving out the error**

```
with open('lastResponse.json', 'r+') as fp:
        f = json.dump(r.json(), fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4) # Where the response data is sent to the JSON
        data = json.load(f) # Line that triggers the error
        print(data["results"]) # Debug code
        print("------------------") # Debug code
        print(data) # Debug code

        # This statement just checks if a license plate is visible
        if data["results"]["plate"] is None:
            print("No car detected!")
        else:
            print("Car with plate number '" + data["results"]["plate"] + "' has been detected")
```

**The Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DetectionFinished.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I am not very experienced in Python so I would appreciate explanations!

Comment: What value are you expecting `f` to have? It doesn't look like json.dump returns anything. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.dump

Comment: @saffronsnail I tested that and if I did `json.load(fp)` I get the error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I am also using that to send that data to the JSON file.

Comment: Have you double checked that fp contains the data you expect it to? It sounds like fp has the correct object type, but bad data

Comment: I put `print(fp)` at the beginning after `with...` and received `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='lastResponse.json' mode='r+' encoding='UTF-8'>`. Also the dump function is writing to the JSON, so it can access the `fp` variable correctly.

Comment: What about print(fd.read())?

Comment: fp.read() does return the JSON data. If I put it in the data variable like `data = json.load(fp.read())` it gives me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Can you post the data? It sounds like it's malformed

Comment: [This is what is written to the lastResponse.json file](https://pastebin.com/FB9MfNqL) Edit: [This is the API I am using](https://platerecognizer.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, after rereading the API's documentation and using their examples I was able to fix my issues

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
regions = ['gb', 'it']
with open('/path/to/car.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    response = requests.post(
        'https://api.platerecognizer.com/v1/plate-reader/',
        data=dict(regions=regions),  # Optional
        files=dict(upload=fp),
        headers={'Authorization': 'Token API_TOKEN'})
pprint(response.json())
```